# Which spell's damage benefits the most from Dangerous Sorcery (relatively)?

Tags: spells, optimization, pathfinder-2e

Dangerous Sorcery adds to the damage of spells that lack a duration, and deal damage.

Which qualifying spell has the lowest damage per level on its own, so DS adds the most relative improvement?

Any official spell is fine, preferably below level 5. The more enemies it can effect the better.

---

Why I would like to find it: PF2 has a pretty good balance, so if a spell tends to do less damage, it usually has other redeeming qualities. Larger area than usual, other effects like sickened (Vomit Swarm), and so on.

Comment: What exactly is your goal of finding the lowest damage spell? Specifically, do you care about the spell that literally gains the most (relative) damage from DS, or are you just concerned with finding the lowest-damage spell? Should the spell be an area effect (most hypothetical benefit) or are you just looking at using it on one target?

Comment: In addition to Ifusaso’s questions, I’m wondering what’s preventing you from reading through the spell list and figuring this out yourself. This seems like a “read the book to me question”.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov If we have to do research and synthesize stuff, it's not merely reading the book to someone. "Read the book to me" is _literally_ just people asking us to repeat what a book they don't have says on a topic, so that they don't have to buy it themselves, which is asking us to engage in copyright violation. Or it's just plain lack of research effort in which case we can call it that. [Meta here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5270/1204).

Comment: I've VTC for now until @Ifusaso's questions are answered. Andras is active and will be back, and we'll be able to better answer their question with some clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As expected, there is never one perfect spell for a given situation, especially since sometimes a spell list will have a similar but notably different version from others. I'm going to note a few spells that will be beneficial, sorted by area types.

### Burst

Burst are possibly the easiest spells to hit a large number of enemies while minimizing friendly fire, making them a good choice even if some of the others are theoretically able to hit more targets. Fireball is also in this area, and the choice between it and *sudden blight* is debatable given the limited scope of *sb*'s added effect, but *sb* comes online sooner and isn't necessarily as well known so I wanted to give it a shout-out. *Sound burst* doesn't have the area of other options, but its additional effects buys it a space on the list.

- *sudden blight* (level 2, Heightened +1)

  - damage: 2-9 d10 negative
  - area: 20ft burst
  - volume: 1,508ft³ (44 squares on a plane, up to approx 200 squares)
  - add'l effect: removes vegetation-based difficult terrain, enemies with disease take a penalty when Saving
- *sound burst* (level 2, Heightened +1)

  - damage: 2-9 d10 sonic
  - area: 10ft burst
  - volume: 754ft³ (12 squares on a plane, up to 32 squares)
  - add'l effect: deafened, stunned 1rd (crit)

### Cone

No list about maximizing area damage would be complete with the resident 60ft cone, the scope of which is tough to grasp in 3 dimensions. *Elemental annihilation wave* actually fits this question better, but costs 2 full turns to do so.

- *elemental annihilation wave* (level 3, +2 Heightened)

  - damage: 4/8/12/16 d6 fire & bludgeoning
  - area: 30ft or 60ft cone
  - volume: 7,069ft³ or 56,549ft³ (24/96 squares on a plane, up to 100-400 squares)
  - add'l effect: knockback, prone (crit), *gust of wind* (1 round)
- *cone of cold* (level 5, +1 Heightened)

  - damage: 12-20 d6 cold
  - area: 60ft cone
  - volume: approx. 56,549ft³ (96 squares on a plane, up to around 400 squares)
  - add'l effect: none

### Cylinder

Oddly, the other cylinder I looked at (*geyser*) has a duration of 1 round and is therefore officially not compatible with Dangerous Sorcery. If your GM is willing to homerule it, *geyser* is a better spell in this circumstance for its larger area and additional effects.

- *flame strike* (level 5, +1 Heightened)

  - damage: 8-16 d6 fire
  - area: 10ft radius/40ft tall
  - volume: 12,566ft³ (96 squares)
  - add'l effect: ignores half fire resist and can affect fire immune creatures

### Line

Lines. Nearly impossible to hit more than a couple of things, but theoretically *so* powerful. This one is hard to decide between <s>kamehameha</s> *inner radiance torrent* and *blazing fissure*, so I went with both for different reasons. Similar to *elemental annihilation wave*, *irt* is probably the better answer but has issues due to it's abnormal casting.

- *inner radiance torrent* (level 2, +1 Heightened)

  - damage: 4(8)-32(64) d4 force
  - area: 60ft or 120ft line
  - volume: 1,500ft³ or 3,000ft³ (120 or 240 squares)
  - add'l effect: counteract darkness, blind 1rd (crit), 1-8 force damage aura
- *blazing fissure* (level 5, +1 Heightened)

  - damage: 10-18 d6 fire & bludgeoning
  - area: 120ft line
  - volume: 3,000ft³ (240 squares)
  - add'l effect: prone

### Other notes:

These spells *might* work with Dangerous Sorcery; they cause persistent damage but don't have a duration themselves. As a GM, I would rule against it (except *grim tendrils* initial damage), but both are good spells in their own right and would be excellent choices when using the feat, if allowed. *Magic missile* isn't helped enough to fully list it out, but suffice to say that you can hit 3, 6, 9, 12, or 15 different targets for 1d4+2 with the combo. Wooo.

- *grim tendrils* (level 1, Heightened +1)

  - damage: 2-18 d4 negative
  - area: 30ft line
  - volume: 750ft³ (60 squares)
  - add'l effect: 1-9 persistent bleed
- *enervation* (level 4, Heightened +2)

  - damage: 4-10 d8 persistent negative
  - area:  30ft line
  - volume: 750ft³ (60 squares)
  - add'l effect: drained, doomed (crit)

---

Source: Used pf2easy.com/spellbook/ to filter to spells with the Traits: Acid, Attack, Cold, Death, Electricity, Fire, Force, Mental, Negative*, and/or Sonic. Also limited search to level 5 (some higher ones, such as *prismatic spray* or *meteor swarm*, would have been likely candidates), then sifted for area effects. *Added Negative under the pretense of the more common situation of facing living enemies; for basically any Negative spell there is a corollary Positive spell that I did not want to sift through but exists if you find yourself fighting undead.

Comment: Lines have the most party friendly shape. Most of the others can only be used effectively when you win the initiative.

Comment: Party friendliness is always relative. Lines aren't so easy to avoid allies in a hallway, and even outside of them it can be difficult if your melee people don't rotate around enemies to get out of your line. Burst you can almost always drop it past your allies to hit swaths of enemies (with the exception of flanking melee)

Comment: As for the spell names, I'm not really sure. That's just how I've been doing it for a while now